# Windows service and MS Access on UNC

Tags: c#, service, ms-access-2010, unc

I am trying to get my Windows service to connect to an MS Acces database that is located on a UNC

```
private static void InsertData(string sql)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();

        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                @"Data source=\\svr\Users\XXXX\XXXXX\db.accdb";


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            WriteToFile("Data saved successfuly...!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          WriteToFile("Failed due to: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get
"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\svr\Users\XXXX\XXXXX\db.accdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."

The permissions are set to domain users, read, write and modify etc. The database is not open by anyone.

I have tried the exact code in a console app and it works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you map the UNC path to a network drive letter?  Do you have read/write permissions also on the directory where the db is placed?

Comment: I have tried using the drive letter too in the service and it says it "X:\xxxx.xxxx is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.". I have permissions on the drive too.

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered where you could have an issue.  I remember having issues with the 64-bit ODBC vs. 32-bit ODBC!

If you are running 32-bit Ms Access you have to use 32-bit ODBC executable at path `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`!

You have to setup the connecting first:

1) *C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe started as administrator and clicking on button add*:

[image: ODBC data source]

2) *Then enter your connection here:*

[image: Connection]

**First edit** An example of filling the ODBC Data Source:

[image: An example how to fill the data source]

Don't forget that afterwards you are addressing your newly create data source.

Comment: Thanks. Would nerver have known about that. Initially did not work but once I set the system database button all was well.

Comment: You are getting an error from your application or the ODBC setup?  Could you add some details?

Comment: @james: did you try it?

Comment: The ODBC setup appears fine, the error occurs in VS2017. I have just tried to write to a text file and get acces denied. The service is running as Local System should it be Network Service?

Comment: @James which service you are talking about?

Comment: It is my service that connects to the database. I have moved the database to a local partition and it is workinf. I think I need to create a user with fixed credentials to use the service.

Comment: @james sounds logical. There are credentials also at avanced button. Im not at computer anymore so I can't do a screenshot.

Comment: @James: It is hard to give you advice when I do not know how you login or use it at your network.  Do you have AD or some kind of LDAP?  If you have AD just put there your account under which you run the service.  It does need to be Local System or Network service.  It can be a "technical" account under which you can operate the service.  Add then the technical account to have rw rights to the directory you have the access file.